# Character model blocky and not smooth and fluent

Tags: modeling, rigging, bones

A while back, I made a character but there was a problem - its joints had cracks, like if you used a block and used another block, then put a bone, then moved that bone in *Edit* mode, there would be a crack from the opposite direction you were moving it. However, in all these videos I see, their models look like one piece and move fluently.

Another thing, I don't want to have to go to *Edit* mode or *Pose* mode because in *Object* mode I'm pretty sure they were just moving it straight "up". I don't get it.

Here is my old model - [image]

Here is my new model -[image]

I just want my new model to look smooth and be one piece and not fifty and also any character that I so make. I can't find one video that explains it, so if you can link me a video and or comment on a solution.

Also, the bones moved weirdly. I'm fine with making a whole new body for my character. So if there is a way I can make a smooth character and not have weird cracks when I move the bones that will be fine, I'll remodel. Please and thanks to all for the solution.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: You need to watch some basic character modelling and rigging videos! There are hundreds online.

Comment: Here are a few things that are good to know regarding the topology and animation [Modeling For Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01WQlMD7dsk&list=PLL3OEv6vd5VA4owAPOI0QdCcEmvl1f3BT) and [Retopology A Detailed Guide - What is Retopology & Why Do We Need It?](https://youtu.be/S4YNiImIgPs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duarte Farrajota Ramos is right that some more images or gifs would be helpful, but I'll try my best to understand your question. I've had a look at your models and see that you've got some experience with modelling, that's good. The problem with the joints that you're describing, it works that way because you've made it that way. With your first model the upper arms, the lower arms and the torso are all separate meshes. You want these to be one mesh.

You say the bones move weird. You have a basic rig but it's not very functional at the moment. John Eason is right that there are many videos to help you out on YouTube, however not all of them respect your time. [Royal Skies](https://www.youtube.com/@TheRoyalSkies/featured) is a channel on YouTube that does very short but information-rich tutorials on Blender. Here are a couple that should help you:

- [Basic Rigging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFaqjwpGxOc)
- [Inverse Kinematics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pt3-mHBCoQk) (to create controls for your rig)
- [Weight painting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fICQmBEt4Y) (to connect your mesh to your rig)

As for the shading, go into object mode, press spacebar and search for 'Shade Smooth'. Using this this will change the shading of whatever object you have selected to smooth shading, like so:
[image: Smooth]

Good luck on your Blender journey!

Edit: Removed my ending comment, seemed a bit rude.